# Null Pointer Exception Error With Arraylist.add Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to make an activity that displays a list of objects in a card, in a recyclerview list. The list in the main activity takes values set by an EditText in a second activity. I got everything working fine, but when I got the intent from the second activity, I got this error, and I get the error even when working with dummy data, which I didn't before.

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
    at jacob.fragile.contactlist.ContactsAdapter$ViewHolder.bindTo(ContactsAdapter.java:69)
    at jacob.fragile.contactlist.ContactsAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ContactsAdapter.java:43)
    at jacob.fragile.contactlist.ContactsAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ContactsAdapter.java:19)
```

As I haven't touched the Contacts Adapter in several days, and it was working before, I don't think there is an issue there. This is my main activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList<Contacts> mContacts;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private ContactsAdapter mAdapter;

//Declare lists to be filled with Data from Add Contact Activity
public static ArrayList<String> nameList = new ArrayList<>();
public static ArrayList<String> ageList = new ArrayList<>();
public static ArrayList<String> colorList = new ArrayList<>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

    mContacts = new ArrayList<>();

    mAdapter = new ContactsAdapter(this, mContacts);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    // Get the data.
    initializeData();

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
}

private void initializeData() {

    //Listen for the intent
    /*Intent intent = getIntent();
    String nameValue = intent.getStringExtra(AddContact.NAME_MESSAGE);
    String ageValue = intent.getStringExtra(AddContact.AGE_MESSAGE);
    String colorValue = intent.getStringExtra(AddContact.COLOR_MESSAGE);*/

    nameList.add("nameValue");
    ageList.add("ageValue");
    colorList.add("colorValue");

    // Get the data from the lists.
    String[] names = nameList.toArray(new String[nameList.size()]);
    String[] age = ageList.toArray(new String[ageList.size()]);
    String[] color = colorList.toArray(new String[colorList.size()]);
    TypedArray imageResources =
                getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.images);
        // Clear the existing data (to avoid duplication).
        mContacts.clear();

        // Create the ArrayList of contacts  with names and
        // ages.
        for(int i=0;i<names.length;i++){
            mContacts.add(new Contacts(names[i],age[i], color[i], imageResources.getResourceId(i, 0)));
        }

        // Notify the adapter of the change.
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        //Recycle the typed array
        imageResources.recycle();

    }

public void fabClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddContact.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

Here's my ContactAdapter.java, though that isn't the actual issue

```
public class ContactsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactsAdapter.ViewHolder> {

public static final String TAG = "RecyclerViewAdapter";

private ArrayList<Contacts> mContacts;
private Context mContext;

public ContactsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Contacts> contacts) {
    this.mContacts = contacts;
    this.mContext = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(mContext).
            inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
Log.d(TAG,"On viewHolder: called");
Contacts contacts = mContacts.get(position);

holder.bindTo(contacts);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {return mContacts.size();}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    ImageView imageView;
    TextView name;
    TextView age;
    TextView color;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contact_image);
        name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        age = itemView.findViewById(R.id.age);
        color = itemView.findViewById(R.id.colorSpinner);
    }

    void bindTo(Contacts contacts) {
        //Set the text views
        name.setText(contacts.getName());
        age.setText(contacts.getAge());
        color.setText(contacts.getColor());
        //Load in the images
        Glide.with(mContext).load(contacts.getImageResource()).into(imageView);

    }
}
```

}

Finally, here's the list_item that the Textviews are setting to. colorSpinner is a spinner in the second activity that gets converted to a string, so using a textview is valid

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="8dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/contact_image"
        android:layout_width="96dp"
        android:layout_height="96dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/contact_image"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="@string/placeholder_name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/age"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/name"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/contact_image"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="@string/placeholder_number"
        android:textColor="?android:textColorSecondary" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/color"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/age"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/contact_image"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="@string/placeholder_color"
        android:textColor="?android:textColorSecondary" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I don't know why there's suddenly an issue. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: are you sending any data to `ContactsAdapter`

Comment: in above code in exactly which line the error is?

Comment: You're calling `setText()` on a null `TextView` in the `ContactsAdapter`'s `ViewHolder`'s `bindTo()` method. Please [edit] your question to provide the `ContactsAdapter` class and the relevant layout XML, and we can get you a more specific answer.

Comment: OK, you are assigning all of those `TextView`s, so that would indicate that at least one of the `<TextView>`'s with ID `name`, `age`, or `colorSpinner` is not in the `list_item` layout. Are you sure `colorSpinner` is the right ID for a `TextView`? Please provide the `list_item` layout.

Comment: Okay, I added them @Mike-M

Comment: Yeah, `colorSpinner` is wrong. Change the following line in your `ViewHolder`'s constructor: `color = itemView.findViewById(R.id.color);`.

Comment: @Mike-M That doesn't fix it. The specific line error goes away, but it still throws a null pointer exception

Comment: It fixes that specific issue, if it was applied successfully. Are you sure it's the _exact_ same Exception and message? If so, clean and rebuild your project, and if that doesn't do it, Invalidate Caches/Restart. If it's still crashing, you'll need to check the current error in your logcat.

Comment: It's not the exact same one, no. But it doesn't throw any different specific error.

Comment: Here's the error  

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{jacob.fragile.contactlist/jacob.fragile.contactlist.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3121)`

Comment: ```Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at jacob.fragile.contactlist.MainActivity.initializeData(MainActivity.java:56)
        at jacob.fragile.contactlist.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)
```
44 is the `initializeData()` call, and 56 is the `nameList.add("nameValue");`

Comment: 44 is `initializeData()` and 56 is `nameList.add("nameValue");`

Comment: I promise that's actually the code I'm running. I tried those things and got the same issue. If it's not too much trouble, if I uploaded this to git, would you try running it and seeing? I was supposed to have this done tomorrow.

Comment: https://github.com/JacobJumper/ContactList Thank you very much

Comment: I made that change before uploading to see if that might help, it still crashes with the same error.

Comment: I'm currently running the same code as what is on Github, and it does crash with the above issue.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. The code you've posted in the question here will not have that issue. That is, with the `= new ArrayList<>()` on all three of those `ArrayList`s.

Comment: It doesn't, but it did before I reset Android Studio. Hm. I'm very sorry. Thank you for your help. I promise it was crashing with the code in my initial post.

Comment: No worries. Cheers!